# Docusign - How to ExportAuthoritativeCopy of a signed envelope using REST API

Tags: docusignapi

I need to export an authoritative copy of a signed envelope out of docusign in order to be able to delete it later. I'm using DocuSign REST API v2.0 in PHP

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's currently possible to do so with the DocuSign REST API -- instead, you'll need to use the DocuSign SOAP API.  See documentation starting with "ExportAuthoritativeCopy" on page 168 of the [DocuSign SOAP API Guide](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSignAPI_Guide.pdf).

Comment: That's correct Kim, AuthoritativeCopy is available through the SOAP API but not the REST API...